# Present ViewController in tabBarController from other file, Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, xib, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to present a ViewController from another swift file. This works if i want to present a ViewController from another ViewController.

This time i want to present a ViewController in a tabBarController from a class which belongs to a xib. This prints: "In new init" in presenter, but not the print: "setting up presenter" in VC. Any ideas why?

(unrelated code is cut out)

Code from class in xib:

```
@IBAction func timerBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "SleepTimerPopup", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SleepTimerPopup_UI") as! SleepTimerPopup_UI
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    let currentController = self.getCurrentViewController()
    currentController?.tabBarController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController? {

    if let rootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        var currentController: UIViewController! = rootController
        while( currentController.presentedViewController != nil ) {
            currentController = currentController.presentedViewController
        }
        return currentController
    }
    return nil
}
```

ViewController which i want to present over current context:

```
class SleepTimerPopup_UI: UIViewController, SleepTimerPopupDelegate{


@IBOutlet var shortcutOutlets: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet weak var timerDoneOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var timePickerOutlet: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var sleepTimerContainerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var sleepTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stopWatchBackgroundView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var stopWatchImage: UIView!

let sleepTimerPopupDelegate = SleepTimerPopupPresenter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupSleepTimerUI()
    setupSleepTimerDelegate()
}

func setupSleepTimerDelegate(){
    print("setting up presenter") <-- THIS IS NOT PRINTED
    sleepTimerPopupDelegate.setSleepTimerViewDelegate(sleepTimerDelegate : self)
}
```

ViewControllerPresenter which i want to present over current context:

```
class SleepTimerPopupPresenter{

weak private var sleepTimerDelegate : SleepTimerPopupDelegate?
static var sleepTimer = SleepTimer(sleepTimerPopupPresenter: SleepTimerPopupPresenter())
static var doneBtnIsSelected = false
private var latestOutlet : UIButton?
private var setTime : (Int, Int)

init(){
    setTime = (0, 0)

    print("in new init") <----- THIS IS PRINTED

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.timeChanged),
        name: Notification.Name("TimeUpdate"),
        object: nil)
}

func setSleepTimerViewDelegate(sleepTimerDelegate : SleepTimerPopupDelegate){
    self.sleepTimerDelegate = sleepTimerDelegate
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can send a notification in "timerBtnAction" while adding an observer in one of the tap bar viewcontrollers. And just present the viewcontroller from the observer func there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your currentViewController?.tabBarController is nil. Usually it is possible when it is not rootViewController of UITabBarController or not in the stack.

You can simply present you view controller like this:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen // .fullScreen
currentVieController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```